# What command do I use to create a password-protected x509 certificate?

Tags: command-line, openssl, certificate, x509, pfx

I created an x509 certificate using openssl. I created the certificate using this openssl command:

```
req -new -x509 -key privkey.der -out cert.pfx
```

where "privkey.der" is the private key I created. I want to make this certificate password protected. Is there a command that would allow me to do so?
Thanks!

Comment: That 'command' only works in `openssl`, which you didn't actually say, and the `-key` file must actually be a privatekey in PEM not DER so your name is misleading and confusing. The certificate output is also PEM and cannot be encrypted; labelling it `.pfx` is also misleading and confusing. You can _combine_ the privatekey and cert (and chain if applicable) in a PKCS12 aka PFX file, which is password protected, using `openssl pkcs12 -export`; there are many many Qs and As about this on several Stacks going back years, but it is not within the current scope of SO (see the help center).

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to use 'pkcs12 -export -out cert.pfx -in privkey.pem -in cert.pem'  (now I created the private key in PEM format), but the command line just freezes and nothing is happening... :c

Comment: If the command is frozen it's probably prompting you for a password, but maybe couldn't output the prompt.